# How do I comment / uncomment a block of code in PsychoPy Builder

Tags: psychopy

How do I comment / uncomment a block of code in PsychoPy Builder?

If I select a number of lines I can in/outdent it as a block using TAB and SHIFT TAB, I want to comment / uncomment the block in a similar way in the Builder interface (handy for when testing)

I've had a search but not found out how yet?

Thanks

Comment: In python in general you can outcomment multiple lines by turning them into a multiline string. Use ``"""``` (three double quotes) before and after the block that you want to outcomment.

Answer (score 2):

It seems that you can comment/uncomment entire blocks of code with Ctrl-' and Ctrl-Shift-'.

Comment: That's true in PsychoPy Coder view, but the Code Component of Builder view doesn't have this set up as yet (to my knowledge)

Answer (score 2):

Sorry, this hasn't been added as a key-binding yet to the Builder Code Component. You'll just have to surround your code with triple quotes, as Jonas suggests